# How to view list all avds of android studio(WIthout starting android studio) & then start avd from command line in linux mint

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, linux-mint

I want to start android studio emulator (avd) from command line in linux mint as well as in windows (Without starting android studio)

Answer (score 0):

Go to emulator's folder

```
cd ${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator
```

First list all your emulators:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Run one of the listed emulators with -avd flag:

```
emulator -avd @name-of-your-emulator
```

Comment: emulator -list-avds this command is not working in linux mint got an error  of emulator command not found

Comment: You need to go inside emulator directory. See changed answer.

Comment: i am inside  /home/Android/Sdk/emulator &&  i also try from Sdk folder

Comment: Could you check if you have a file named emulator or not inside that directory.

Comment: i am on linux mint while apply your command as per your suggestion i got an error of following : emulator : commnad not found